# aspnet core linux environment variables

Tags: asp.net-core

I trying to use swagger on my linux machine, so I used default microsoft example code to enable it only in development
`

```
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development")
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }
```

`

Using ubuntu 20.04
environtment variable was set by this command to linux - export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development.

But when I deploy my application, swagger is not available. But if a remove if statement,  swagger works fine. So I think there is the problem with environment variable, somehow .net could not access it or see it.

I tried manually set environment variable in linux, result - variable not visible. A tried to set variable in azure devops pipeline variables - not worked. Added log on app start to see what is the value of variable - Production. I just do not understand how do I set environment. Tried to add new configuration  - staging, and in azure YAML setting
`buildConfiguration: 'Staging'`
, and adding
`if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsStaging())`

- nothing works.

Comment: That `if()` is not "default microsoft example code". You should not read the environment variables directly (as they can be passed in various ways including command line arguments); you should obtain them from the `IHostEnvironment`. What do you mean that you tried to manually set the environment variable and it was "not visible"?

Comment: Yes, Thank you, I changed code to             if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsStaging())
still nothing changed

Comment: How do you "deploy the application"? If running locally, make sure dotnet is executed in the same terminal context - e.g. running in another terminal window or even using sudo creates new session without manually defined variables. If deploying to app service, using app settings is the way to properly set environment variables https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-app-settings

Answer (score 0):

Found problem. ASP.NET Core read environment variables on linux from file, that on path /proc/{process id (PID)}/environ. Environment variables there are different from linux general variables. To see your process variables find you process PID and then execute `cat /proc/3213/environ | tr '\0' '\n'` - 3213 example PID